# WPF in DataGrid Width * looks different when running on my computer

Tags: wpf, datagrid, width

I have a very strange problem: 
I have recently got a new computer. When running the application on my new computer, in all DataGrids that has a line that looks like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Modell" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Model}" MaxWidth="200" />
```

all columns get Width 20 (even those with a specified Width). This is whether I run in from VS or just doubleclick the exe. If the very same exe (which I compiled myself) is copied and run on other machines, it work perfectly.

However if I change the Width to the folowing:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Modell" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding Model}" MaxWidth="200" />
```

All the columns look fine.

What could cause that?

Comment: do you have some user settings?

Answer (score 0):

Different machine means different hardware, so you may be experiencing problems due to hardware acceleration.  Try switching from hardware rendering to software rendering by adding this to your App.xaml.cs file:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {

        RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't help. :-(